# How to eliminate items from listbox when textbox changed

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, listbox, letter

I wanna make a small code block about c #.

first think a listbox with elements.
then think a blank textbox.

when I write a letter to textbox(dont think just letter, think about a word ,I split it with textbox1_textchanged ),if an element dont have the word it must be deleted from listbox.

example:

here are listbox elements :

```
abraham
michael
george
anthony
```

when i type "a",I want michael and george to be deleted,then when I type "n" I want abraham to be deleted(at this point total string is "an")...

Thanks by now (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string item = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            foreach(char theChar in textBox1.Text)
            {
                if(item.Contains(theChar))
                {
                    //remove the item, consider the next list box item
                    //the new list box item index would still be i
                    listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. It will match what you have in the textbox and remove what doesn't match.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < textBox1.Text.Length  ; j++)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text[j] != listBox1.Items[i].ToString()[j])
            {
                if (i < 0) break;
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                i = i - 1; // reset index to point to next record otherwise you will skip one
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the items that doesn't contain the text and remove them from the listbox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemsToRemove = listBox1.Items.Cast<object>().Where(x => !x.ToString().Contains(textBox1.Text)).ToList();
    foreach(var item in itemsToRemove)
        listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: listBox1.Items.Where ? there is no extension where!!

Comment: Ok, I edited it to support the extension method. Instead of just complaining (and I guess voting down), you could just edited it! It's for giving an idea of the solution, not for @alicanbatur to copy and paste it to his production code!

Comment: @ivowiblo There is not a ListBoxItem in Winforms only in WPF, ListBox.Items are returned as objects, You are also modifying the enumerator which is throwing an error.